# ASP.NET core binding fails due to null field value marked with [JsonIgnore]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

An ASP.NET controller accepts an object which looks similar to this one:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
    [JsonIgnore] public int Length => Text.Length;
}
```

Text property value is optional. However, when it is null then MVC fails during model binding. For some reason, the MVC binding code tries to access the Length field and gets an exception due to the null Text.

I naively assumed that **JsonIgnore** attribute would be taken into account by MVC or at least it would not try to deserialize the read-only property. How can I hide this property from MVC binding? Is there an attribute that works as JsonIgnore that MVC understands?

The platform is .net core 2.1

**EDIT:**
The marked answer pointed me in the right direction. I disabled validation based on information from this page [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

In ConfigureServices startup object I added this line:

```
services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator>(new NullObjectModelValidator());
```

and created NullObjectModelValidator

```
public class NullObjectModelValidator : IObjectModelValidator
{
    public void Validate(ActionContext actionContext, 
        ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model)
    {
    }
}
```

It is not the right solution in every case but if data does not need validation then this approach works.

Comment: The `JsonIgnore` does ignore it from being `JSON` serialized.  That isn't your problem.  Your problem is that `Text` is null so `Text.Length` gives a null ref exception.  Try this instead `Text?.Length ?? 0`.

Comment: MVC binding is accessing that property right after de-serialization. It does not make any sense toe me.

Comment: As soon as you instantiate that object, whether it was from de/serialization or from a `new Data()` doesn't matter, the instance will automatically try to calculate `Length`.  As soon as it does that you will get the error.

Comment: I know how properties work. I am having problem with MVC validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - if you pass the data from form to the Controller by usual way it is not passed as Json, but as `FormData`, in `Url Encoded Form` (example: `Text=&Length=4`). So `JsonIgnore` is irelevant here.

Next thing is, that `ModelBinder` does not try to bind value to the Length (as it is read-only). It sets only the `Text` to the `null` value. Then it tries to apply some default validation, which includes traversing the object, getting its values and apply validation attributes. 
And here comes your error as described in comment and @nurdyguy answer: property `Length` accesses property `Length` of `null` object. So solution here is:

```
public int Length => Text?.Length ?? 0;
```

Another solution, which I do not recommend is to skip the validation on the field by:

```
[ValidateNever]public int Length => Text?.Length ?? 0;
```

But this only hides the error in your code, which is still there.

BTW: if you really need sometime to exclude some property from model binding, use `[BindNever]` attribute on the property (but here it does not solve your problem, as described before).

Comment: I have no validation attributes at all. What is MVC binder doing? Why is it even checking all properties? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: You do not have to. As far as I understand from the ASP.NET Core source code, it cycle through objects properties, get their values, with possible attributes and pass them to the validation function, which ensure validation. Maybe it is kind of error in the ASP.NET - maybe it should find out if validation is necessary and then validate the value. Maybe it is intention - I do not know. Check https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Validation/ValidationVisitor.cs for the code which causes your problem in function `VisitChildren`.

Comment: Note about validation pointed me in the right direction. I found the solution here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0  in "Disable validation" section.

Answer (score 0):

What the `[JsonIgnore]` tag does is tells the model binder to ignore that value when de/serializaing `JSON` to a poco.  That *is* functioning correctly and is not the problem here.  Your problem is that `[JsonIgnore] public int Length => Text.Length;` will fail when `Text` is null because `Text.Length` throws a null reference exception.  This is totally independent of the `[JsonIgnore]`.  You defined the property `Length` as being set based on a calculation.  Whether the `[JsonIgnore]` tag is there or not this value must calculate because it is part of the model.

One way to fix your issue is to use null coalescence:

```
[JsonIgnore] public int Length => Text?.Length ?? 0;
```

This way, when `Text` is null the `Text?.Length` returns null and then the `??` checks for null and returns 0.  Another option would be to let `Length` be a nullable int:

```
[JsonIgnore] public int? Length => Text?.Length;
```

So now the `Length` will be null when `Text` is null but have a value when `Text` is not null.  The downfall is that you'll have to do work elsewhere dealing with the value being a nullable int vs regular int.